# How to prove that the $n$-sphere $S^n$ is path connected for $n\geq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, path-connected

How would I prove that the $n$-sphere $S^n$ is path connected for $n\geq 1$?

I have seen [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319924/for-n-geq-2-mathbbrn-and-an-n-dimensional-sphere-are-path-connected) I do not really understand this section:

> For b) The application $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ to $S^{n-1}$ defined by $x \to x/\Vert x \Vert_2$ is continuous. If $x,y$ are on the sphere and not on a diameter, the path $\varphi([x,y])$ is continuous and join  $x$ to $y$ on the sphere. If $x$, $y$ are on a diameter, $\varphi([x,z][z,y])$ is a solution.

What is $\varphi$? What is $x/||x||_2$?

This is my proof attempt:

*Proof:*
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

We want to show that the $n$-sphere is path connected for $n\geq 1$.

Let $S^n$ be an $n$-sphere where $n\geq 1$. Then $S^n\subseteq\R^{n+1}$.

We know $\R^{n+1}$ is path connected, as is every open and every closed ball in $\R^n$.

Let $f:\R^{n+1}\to S^n$ be a function ???. (What would this be?)

Then by Theorem 6.29, $f(\R^{n+1}) = S^n$ is a path connected subspace of $S^n$

Because $S^n$ is path connected in the subspace topology that $S^n$ inherits from $S^n$, we have that $S^n$ is path connected in $S^n$.

In other words, the $n$-sphere $S^n$ is path connected for $n\geq 1$.

$\square$

Thank you for any help you can provide.

EDIT: Removed textbook specific definition and theorem references.

Comment: Hint: First prove that continuous image of a path connected space is path connected. Then show that the mapping $x\mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is continuous and surjective. Here $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Another way to go is to prove that $S^n$ is homeomorphic to the suspension of $S^{n-1}$, and is therefore path-connected.

Comment: A third way to go is to show that $S^n\setminus \{u\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ for any $u\in S^n.$

Comment: To answer your questions directly, $\phi$ is the function with domain $\mathbb R^n$ and range $S^{n-1}$ and with formula $x \mapsto x / ||x||_2$, for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Often this is written more succinctly as $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to S^{n-1}$ with formula $\phi(x) = x / ||x||_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ is path-connected: take straight line segments between any two points in $X$ and if that line segment would go through $0$, take a path via a third non-origin point so that both line segments mis $0$.

$f: X \to \mathbb{S}^n$ given by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i+1}^{n+1} x_i^2}} \cdot x$$

(or $f(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ more succinctly) is a well-defined continuous map whose image is exactly $\Bbb S^n$ and the continuous image of a path-connected space is path-connected.